# Stacked and normal Bar Series on single Chart in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I make two bars on one/single chart.

a) Standard Bar (Series1)
b) Stacked Bar (Series2 and Series3)

I use Delphi 10.3.1 and TChart component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign different values of `StackGroup` property to `Series1` and `(Series2 and Series3)`

[image]